# How to make IntelliJ show the real names for method parameters?

Tags: java

How to I setup the IDEA IDE, so that it shows real param names for methods in build-in classes?

[image]

`mvn clean install dependency:sources` did not help me

upd:
HttpExchange from package
`import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpExchange`

Comment: Are you trying to attach your own sources when you build? Or to download the sources of libraries you use?

Comment: @ernest_k  to download the sources of external libraries

Comment: [not absolutely sure about this] `com.sum` is probably not open source. And one shouldn't be using it directly anyway (it is not standard java).

Comment: Probably the library you are using is compiled that way - the owners decided not to share the variable names. You probably should try to find the open source version if exists.

Answer (score 0):

The library you want to use does not have debug information included in the bytecode which is (for now) needed for this to work.  Source is not enough.

If you cannot locate a debug build you may have to compile it yourself.  If you cannot access the source, you may need to ask the vendor politely.